# Altenative to Gridster

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, gridster

Im trying to find a similar solution to a auto-resize grid system like gridster.

Basically i am creating a grid/dashboard/table system where i receive a dynamically structure of elements like this:

- rowPos:1,colPos:1,rowSpan:1,colSpan:1
- rowPos:2,colPos:1,rowSpan:2,colSpan:1
- rowPos:1,colPos:3,rowSpan:1,colSpan:2
- rowPos:1,colPos:4,rowSpan:1,colSpan:1
- rowPos:2,colPos:4,rowSpan:1,colSpan:1

[image]

since each element is independently from each other i need to set it´s html like the grisdter system:

```
<li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>
```

I implemented the gridster in my project and worked well, but i need a responsive grid.
I don´t need the **drag and drop** support of the gridster, only a similar structure to create the html.

Any ideas, or projects you can suggest to a similar solution. I´m kind of new in the web world. I finded a lot of projects but they all handle automatically the positions of the elements by it´s size.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of options for responsive-grids. I like responsivegridsystem.com, or Foundation's. But if you search for "responsive grid system" you'll get a bunch of choices.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Joes. i am already using the bootstrap framework in my project, but i need a different kind of solution. I can't have a limitation of columns or rows for example. And my html will be ejected dynamically, so i can't make calculations between the elements of the list.